# CSV to NESTED JSON

Tags: csv, json, javascript

I need to convert a CSV file to a JSON output, I'm using the csvtojason library from https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvtojson,
 csv File:

```
mode,device,stb,data,data1,data2,data3,data4
modelo1,device1,stb1,data1,data2,data3,data4
modelo1,device2,stb1,data1,data2,data3,data4
modelo2,device1,stb1,data1,data2,data3,data4
modelo2,device1,stb2,data1,data2,data3,data4
modelo2,device2,stb1,data1,data2,data3,data4
modelo2,device2,stb2,data1,data2,data3,data4
modelo2,device2,stb3,data1,data2,data3,data4
```

code used to convert the json

```
csv = require('csvtojson')
csvFilePath = './CSVFile.csv'
  csv()
    .fromFile(csvFilePath)
    .then((jsonObj) => {
      console.log(jsonObj)
      res.send(jsonObj);
    })
```

But The output is far away from what I expected:

```
[ { mode: 'modelo1',
    device: 'device1',
    stb: 'stb1',
    data: 'data1',
    data1: 'data2',
    data2: 'data3',
    data3: 'data4' },
  { mode: 'modelo1',
    device: 'device2',
    stb: 'stb1',
    data: 'data1',
    data1: 'data2',
    data2: 'data3',
    data3: 'data4' },
  { mode: 'modelo2',
    device: 'device1',
    stb: 'stb1',
    data: 'data1',
    data1: 'data2',
    data2: 'data3',
    data3: 'data4' },
  { mode: 'modelo2',
    device: 'device1',
    stb: 'stb2',
    data: 'data1',
    data1: 'data2',
    data2: 'data3',
    data3: 'data4' },
  { mode: 'modelo2',
    device: 'device2',
    stb: 'stb1',
    data: 'data1',
    data1: 'data2',
    data2: 'data3',
    data3: 'data4' },
  { mode: 'modelo2',
    device: 'device2',
    stb: 'stb2',
    data: 'data1',
    data1: 'data2',
    data2: 'data3',
    data3: 'data4' },
  { mode: 'modelo2',
    device: 'device2',
    stb: 'stb3',
    data: 'data1',
    data1: 'data2',
    data2: 'data3',
    data3: 'data4' } ]
```

I'm expecting to get something like this:

```
[{
    modelo1 : {
        device1: {
            stb1:[data:'data1',data2:'data2',data3:'data3',data4:'data4']
        }
        device2: {
            stb1:[data:'data1',data2:'data2',data3:'data3',data4:'data4']
        }
    }
    modelo2 : {
        device1: {
            stb1: [data:'data1',data2:'data2',data3:'data3',data4:'data4']
            stb2: [data:'data1',data2:'data2',data3:'data3',data4:'data4']
        }
        device2: {
            stb1: [data:'data1',data2:'data2',data3:'data3',data4:'data4']
            stb2: [data:'data1',data2:'data2',data3:'data3',data4:'data4']
            stb3: [data:'data1',data2:'data2',data3:'data3',data4:'data4']
        }
    }
}]
```

Any idea is there is an easy way to do it?

Comment: Your expected output is invalid JSON. An array in JSON is written as e.g. `"stb1": [ "data1", "data2", "data3", "data4" ]`. You also lack commas between objects. Note that the JSON that you do get is actually easier to query than the JSON that you propose, as the keys are derived from the column headings rather than from the table data.

Comment: It was just an sample in how I would like it, let me fix it to the exact format

Comment: Do you need to do in javascript, or is it ok a commandline tool?

Comment: Any way that I can solve it is ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer, using D3 libary is very easy

https://d3js.org/d3-collection.v1.min.js

on my .js file:

```
            var groupedJson = d3.nest()
                .key(function (d) { return d.model; })
                .key(function (d) { return d.device; })
                .key(function (d) { return d.stb; })
                .entries(json);
            console.log(groupedJson);
```